# Controllability set of a restricted control problem

Tags: control-theory

I'm having trouble proving the following:

For $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{3x1}$, $U\subset\mathbb{R}$, consider the restricted control problem:

$\dot x=Ax+Bu$, $x(0)=x_{0}$, $u(t)\in U$

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&0&1\\0&1&0\\0&1&0\\\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Let $U=[-1,1]$.

Prove that the controllable set $C\subset \{x_0:|[x_0]_2|<1\}$.

The fixed time t controllable set is defined as follows:
$C(t)= \{x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n \ \exists u\in\mathbb{U} : x(t)=0\}$ and $\mathbb{U}=\{u:[0,\infty)\to U\subset\mathbb{R}^m | u(.) \text{is measureable}\}$ is the set of admissible controls.

Then the controllable set is $C=\cup_{t>0}C(t)$.

I have absolutely no idea how to do this.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What is the definition of the controllable set? And how do you define $[x]_2$?

Comment: @amsmath I have added the definitions to the original question. As for the other definition I have no idea. Maybe the integer part?

Comment: Thanks for editing. But please edit back replacing $n$ and $m$ by $3$ and $1$. Why did you change that BTW?

Comment: @amsmath I was editing it at the same time as you were so when I submitted mine it didn't take into account your edits. I'll fix it now

Comment: @Dmitry Ah OK. How do you know that?

Comment: @amsmath I don't understand how the union of C(t) works for determining the the controllable set C. Could you care to explain? That's the final key part. It's not explain in my lecture notes and the final answer is very similar.

Comment: @TommySmith97 I don't understand your question.

Comment: @amsmath the controllable set is $C=\cup_{t>0}C(t)$. How exactly do you find out C? I don't know how to take the union of C(t). For example if $C(t)=[-1+e^{-t}, 1-e^{-t}]$ why is it that $C=(-1,1)$?

Comment: @Dmitry I thought so, too. But the statement is false. If you take, e.g., $u(t) = 1$, then I can choose a huge $t$ to satisfy $x(t) = 0$ with $x_0$ given in my comment. But then $x_0$ is huge because there is a $t^2$ in the first entry.

Comment: @TommySmith97 You have $C(t)\subset\mathbb R^3$. Why do you come up with an interval? However, your example is trivial. Since $e^{-t}$ shrinks to zero as $t\to\infty$, for large $t$ your interval is $[-1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$ with a tiny $\epsilon > 0$. This is almost $(-1,1)$. Letting $\epsilon\to 0$ then leads to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: @Dmitry Yeah I get that too... I don't know where to go from integrating RHS and using $|u|\leq 1$ in the integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general solution is$$x(t) = e^{tA}x_0 + \int_0^te^{(t-s)A}Bu(s)\,ds.$$Since $A^2=A^3=\ldots$, one has
$$
e^{tA} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^nA^n}{n!} = I_3 + tA + A^2\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!} = I_3 + tA + (e^t - t - 1)A^2.
$$
Now, if $x_0\in C$, there exist $t>0$ and $u\in\mathbb U$ such that $x(t) = 0$, i.e.,
$$
e^{tA}x_0 = -\int_0^te^{(t-s)A}Bu(s)\,ds.
$$
Applying $e^{-tA}$ from the left gives
\begin{align*}
x_0
&= -\int_0^tu(s)e^{-sA}B\,ds = -\int_0^tu(s)(I - sA + (e^{-s}+s-1)A^2)B\,ds\\
&= -\int_0^tu(s)\begin{pmatrix}e^{-s}+s-1\\ e^{-s}\\ e^{-s}-1\end{pmatrix}\,ds.
\end{align*}
Hence, for the second entry of $x_0$ we have
$$
|[x_0]_2| = \left|\int_0^tu(s)e^{-s}\,ds\right|\le\int_0^t|u(s)|e^{-s}\,ds\le\int_0^te^{-s}\,ds = \left[-e^{-s}\right]_0^t = 1-e^{-t}\,<\,1.
$$

Comment: Oh that notation means the second entry! I get it now!! Thanks so much.

Comment: @TommySmith97 It is convention here that, if a question has been answered, the original poster votes it up and checks it as answered.

Comment: sorry yes I always have done. Have done it now. Was just checking something. Again I very much appreciate your help.